# Firebase Grouping of Users

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, database-design

I am making an Android app in which I am authenticating the users with their phone numbers in Firebase. I want to make the app work like this: If a user wants to make a group (like in Whatsapp) with the existing users, he/she can select the users (by entering the phone number) and create a group.
I need to know how can I map the relation between users and groups in Firebase?

Answer (score 1):

Simply like this:

```
Firebase-root
   |
   --- users
   |     |
   |     --- uid
   |          |
   |          --- userName: "John"
   |          |
   |          --- emailAddress: "John@email.com"
   |          |
   |          --- phoneNumber: 0123456789
   |          |
   |          --- groups
   |                |
   |                --- groupIdOne: true
   |                |
   |                --- groupITwo: true
   |
   --- groups
         |
         --- groupId
              |
              --- groupName: "My Group"
              |
              --- users
                   |
                   --- uidOne: true
                   |
                   --- uidTwo: true
```

Using this schema, you can query the database to display all users, all groups, all groups a user is apart and all users from a particular group.

Comment: @ShaifaliRajput Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's Simple create a node `group` inside it create nodes for groups with user ids
for example

```
group
   user_1_group
         user_2
         user_3
         user_4 
         ....

   user_2_group
         user_5
         user_6
         user_7
         ....
```

You just need to put user id's in that then you can access user info by their id's.